# Trouble with Comboboxes

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, combobox

I am having trouble with checking comboboxes.

Basically on Form load, the code will check the combobox for a string and when it finds one it will split the string up into seperate values and then parse a database for the required information.

I think I have the code I need but it doesn't work

Here is the code:

```
private void cboSelectEmp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cboSelectEmp.Text != string.Empty && cboSelectEmp.Text != "")
        {
            SelectEmployeeInfo();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("");
        }
    }


    private void SelectEmployeeInfo()
    {
        string input = cboSelectEmp.Text.Trim();
        string formFirstNameValue = input.Split(' ')[0];
        string formLastNameValue = input.Split(' ')[1].Replace(",", "");
        txtFirstName.Text = formFirstNameValue;
        txtLastName.Text = formLastNameValue;   
    }
```

When the form loads This code executes and throws an error on the line:

```
string formLastNameValue = input.Split(' ')[1].Replace(",", "");
```

**An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in EmployeeTracker.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

I don't know what I am doing wrong, the form is loaded with the combobox.SelectedIndex = -1 and the if statement checks for no string value.

Any Help Would Be greatly Appreciated

Comment: Your array contains fewer than two elements, therefore there is no element at index 1 for it to look for.  What is the value of ``input`` when you reach that line?  Also, you can use ``String.IsNullOrEmpty`` to simplify your empty string checks.

Comment: Hi, the input string will always be in the format of FirstName LastName, (Position)

EG - John Doe, (Manager)

Comment: That's what you're expecting it to be, not what it actually is, otherwise you wouldn't be getting that error.  It sounds like you're getting this error when the SelectedIndex is -1, if that's the case, add a check in your SelectedIndexChanged method, and don't call ``SelectEmployeeInfo`` when the SelectedIndex < 0.

Comment: throws An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in EmployeeTracker.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: [current code](http://pastebin.com/WM8SFh11)

Comment: My work network doesn't let me see that website so I can't see what you're doing differently.  I would put a breakpoint on the line in question and check the value of ``input``.  You could also check that ``input.Split(' ').Length > 1`` before trying to use ``input.Split(' ')[1]``.

Comment: 'if (cboSelectEmp.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                SelectEmployeeInfo();
            }'

Throws no errors and the form opens successfully but the SelectEmployeeInfo method never runs but using >= the exception is thrown and the input value is "System.Data.DataRowView"

Comment: Well there's your answer, ``System.Data.DataRowView`` split by ``' '`` doesn't have a second element in the array, so you're getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to access it.  You need to use ``cboSelectEmp.SelectedText`` instead.

Comment: Using your method of  checking if input.Split(' ').Length > 1 before executing the Split() Method, worked and the data now throws no exceptions and displays the data properly thank you. if only i could mark a comment as an answer. Please submit your solution as an answer so i can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code:

```
private void cboSelectEmp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboSelectEmp.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            SelectEmployeeInfo();
        }

    }


    private void SelectEmployeeInfo()
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cboSelectEmp.Text.Trim()))
        {
           string input = cboSelectEmp.Text.Trim();
            if (input.Split(' ').Length > 1)
            {
                string formFirstNameValue = input.Split(' ')[0];
                txtFirstName.Text = formFirstNameValue;
                string formLastNameValue = input.Split(' ')[1].Replace(",", "");
                txtLastName.Text = formLastNameValue;
            }

        }

    }
```

throws no exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing an item at an index which doesn't exist in the array returned by the call to `Split();`:

```
input.Split(' ')[1].Replace(",", "");
```

It's likely that the input string doesn't have a space in it e.g:

> stackoverflow

I would also ensure that you have some text to work with before splitting:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cboSelectEmp.Text.Trim())
{
    string formFirstNameValue = input.Split(' ')[0];
    string formLastNameValue = input.Split(' ')[1].Replace(",", "");

    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi, the input string will always be in the format of FirstName LastName, (Position)

Comment: when the form is loaded the combobox has a selected index of -1 meaning that the .Text property will be either null or empty

Comment: @NattyMan0007 If the text is null or empty, you will get this error too. You will need to check that you have some text before doing the split, e.g: `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("");`

Comment: Using this code: 

        private void SelectEmployeeInfo()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cboSelectEmp.Text.Trim()))
            {
                string input = cboSelectEmp.Text.Trim();
                string formFirstNameValue = input.Split(' ')[0];
                string formLastNameValue = input.Split(' ')[1].Replace(",", "");
                txtFirstName.Text = formFirstNameValue;
                txtLastName.Text = formLastNameValue;   
            }  
               
        }

Comment: An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in EmployeeTracker.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: sorry i can't answer my own question for another 8 hours

Comment: [code](http://pastebin.com/uvPazdEq)

Comment: That's essentially the code that I provided, is there something wrong with my answer..?

Comment: it throws an exception, same one

Comment: @NattyMan0007 It's identical to the code you posted on pastebin..

Comment: but what's wrong with it? why does it throw an exception

Comment: @NattyMan0007 What is the input string? Post some sample data.

Comment: The input string will always be in the format of FirstName LastName, (Position)

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by checking if input.Split(' ').Length > 1 before executing the Split() Method

Comment: Erm, there are no exceptions when using that input, even without the null or empty check.

Comment: [code solution](http://pastebin.com/mhXRmupw)